# Regular Expression in java to accepts word which start and end with same letter

Tags: regex

How to define regular expression in java which accepts only those words which starts and end with a

Comment: Something like this should work for you `\b(\w)\w+\1\b` for starts and ends with same letter (your question title). If you mean starts and ends with "a" specifically: `\ba\w+a\b`

Comment: yes it is working, can you explain how it is working

Comment: Sure! See answer, since it required more info than comment limit

Comment: This did not deserve to be closed. The linked answer provides info on how to read a pattern. It does not answer the actual question posted.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you `\b(\w)\w+\1\b` for starts and ends with same letter (your question title).

**Explanation:**

`\b` signifies a word boundary - basically anything `\w` would not match.

`(\w)` match a single word character and captures it to group 1.

`\w+` matches for one or more word characters (to match the rest of the word)

`\1` is a back reference to what the capture group 1 matched, to ensure last letter is same as first